# Android xml cloneNode

Tags: android, xml

The cloneNode() method seems to be buggy. When I call this method I get a DOMException whith code "NAMESPACE_ERR".

Here is my code :

```
DocumentBuilder builder= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.newDocument();
Node n1 = doc.createElement("node");
Node n2 = n1.cloneNode(true);
```

Any idea ? Thank you in advance!

EDIT : 
Important note : this code works perfectly if I run it on my computer with the Java JRE. It only fails on Android (1.6 and 2.2)

EDIT2 : and it works on Andrid 3.1. But I need to use the 2.2 version. Is there a workaround ?

---

Ok, I found a related bug : 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2735

but now I need a workaround... any idea ?
NB : i don't want to add namespace to the created nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and seems to work fine. I got the following in the Log

```
11-17 16:51:54.942: I/(15474): org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.ElementImpl@41413f88
11-17 16:51:54.942: I/(15474): org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.ElementImpl@41414040
```

Code

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    try {
        builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        Log.e("","exception,e");
    }
    Document doc = ((javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder) builder).newDocument();
    Node n1 = doc.createElement("node");
    Node n2 = n1.cloneNode(true);
        Log.i("",n1.toString());
        Log.i("",n2.toString());

}
});
```